# Make Merge option in IMS conference call invisible after max participants being reached

Tags: android

I am trying to grey out the merge button after the maximum participants being reached in an IMS conference call, Currently merge button visible after maximum participants reached and it will throw a toast error message of unable to conference can anyone suggest how to grey out merge option after reached maximum participants?

Comment: What is the maximum number of participants and do you have any way of checking how many participants there are? If you can get both numbers, then what you can do is check if they are equal and then change the button color by doing `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);` Then, you can restrict additional participants from merging into the call.

Comment: grey out in the sense it should be invisible after 6 calls for 7th participant merge button should not be there

Comment: you can do `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: maybe better at https://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to disable the button as well and prevent more people from joining in the call. 
Try to create a selector drawable in your resources with the button state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#D3D3D3" /> 
  <item android:color="#000"/> <!--default color-->
</selector>
```

set that as your button background:

```
android:background="@drawable/the_above_drawable"
```

Once you hit the maximum users just disable the button:

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Hi Nikos I have to do changes in the framework side not in android studio and for the specific operators which uses IMS for conference , operators using IMS only has this problem for other operators it is working fine

Comment: basically its google open source code and you can check in http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/services/telephony/ImsConference.java

Comment: but where is the merge button? Aren't you in control of the layout?

Comment: we should disable it by logic